# Batch converting MP3 and still image PNG to MP4 videos

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

What do I type in the Windows cmd for this to work? I found a code that should work on Linux but I'm on Windows. The Linux code is:

```
for mp3 in "*.mp3"; do ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -i picture.png -framerate 60 \
-i $mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy "${mp3%.*}.mp4";
```

Typing this in Windows cmd does not work, so what should I type?

I want multiple audio files + an image merged into multiple video files.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Command Prompt equivalent is:

```
for %i in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -i picture.png -framerate 60 ^
-i "%i" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy "%~ni.mp4"
```

Note: This will work when typed in interactively but if you are running it as a script you will need to prefix the variables with %% instead of %.

Comment: Necrocomment: `-framerate` should be used as an input option so it should go before `-i picture.png`. Otherwise `-framerate` will be ignored and the default `-framerate 25` will be applied.

Comment: Also more options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

### New Way with Still Image with the FFmpeg Batch AV Converter app from kind share from [this post from Eibel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018786/10789707)

0. Put your image and audio files in a same folder

---

[image: Put your image and audio files in a same folder]

1. Open FFmpeg Batch App and click Add Files

---

[image: Open FFmpeg Batch App and click Add Files]

2. Select all your audio Files

---

[image: Select all your audio Files]

3. Click Cancel

---

[image: Click Cancel]

4. Parameters Field code

---

For m4a audio Files:

`-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -r 10 -crf 23 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1280:720 -map 1:a:0 -c:a aac -b:a 128K -shortest`

For mp3 or aac audio Files:

`-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -r 10 -crf 23 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1280:720 -map 1:a:0 -c:a copy -b:a 128K -shortest`

[image: Parameter Field code]

5. Pre-Input Field Code

---

Modify according to your path to direct to your audio files/image file folder location

`-loop 1 -i "C:\Users\user\Desktop\batcher\1.jpg" -r 10`

[image: Pre-Input Field Code]

6. Ctrl-A - select all audio Files under the Batch processing tab

---

[image: Ctrl-A - select all audio Files under the Batch processing tab]

7. Right Click-Encode (all audio File in list)

---

[image: Right Click-Encode (all audio File in list)]

8. Success

---

[image: Success]

Answer (score 0):

## An alternative solution without still image (for just Black Background mp4s)

by [Caleb_Widogast_Fan](https://www.reddit.com/user/Caleb_Widogast_Fan/) from this post [Convert m4a files to mp3](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/s00jn6/comment/hrzttjb/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

## mp3 to mp4 conversion:

First, put all the mp3 files (`.mp3` or `.m4a` or `.m4a` or any audio file extension) in a same folder.

Then, create a new text file (`.txt`) and copy paste in it this:

```
echo off
mkdir output
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" "output\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

Then save the text file as a  file (i.e. just change the text file extension from `.txt` to `.bat`).

Then put your `.bat` file in the same folder with all the mp3 files.
Then double click the `.bat` file.
It should launch ffmpeg in a loop converting every `.mp3` file in the folder to a `.mp4` with black background in a new folder named "output" inside the same folder as the `.mp3` files.

## Other Audio Format to Mp4 Conversion examples:

### m4a to mp4 conversion example

```
echo off
mkdir output
for %%a in ("*.m4a") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" "output\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

### m4v to mp4 conversion example

```
echo off
mkdir output
for %%a in ("*.m4v") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" "output\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

### Any other

For any other audio file format, just edit the extension after with the `###` characters:

```
for %%a in ("*.###")
```

Answer (score 0):

### NEW OPTIMIZED SETTINGS (kindly shared in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50018786/10789707) by [Eibel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8574095/eibel))

(0. Follow the same process as laid out in [the previous post](https://superuser.com/a/1706004/1105013) above.)

1. Resize Your Image to video Standard:

Image size should be video standard, like 1280x720, 1920x1080).

2. ---Parameters:

For m4a audio files:

`-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf fps=1 -map 1:a:0 -c:a aac -b:a 128K -shortest`

For mp3 or aac audio files:

`-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf fps=1 -map 1:a:0 -c:a copy -b:a 128K -shortest`

[image: Parameters]

3. ---Pre input (PUT YOUR OWN IMAGE FOLDER PATH BETWEEN THE QUOTATION MARKS"):

`-loop 1 -r 1/1 -i "C:\Users\user\Desktop\batcher\1.jpg"`

[image]